# how to show and hide elements created dynamically from array using a select in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have created this 3 mat-cards from an array of objects, these objects have a property called bookingPrice. I want to show the ones which bookingPrice values are greater than 2000. This is the HTML for the cards.

```
<div class="mat-card-wrapper">
    <mat-card #maty *ngFor="let person of dataArray">
        <mat-card-title-group>
            <mat-card-subtitle>
                <span class="boldy">BookingId:</span>
                <span>
                    {{person.bookingId}}
                </span>
                <span class="boldy"> Cliente:</span>
                <span>
                    {{person.locationId.tutenUser.firstName +" "+
                    person.locationId.tutenUser.lastName}}
                </span>
                <span class="boldy">Fecha de Creación</span>
                <span>{{person.bookingTime}}</span>
                <span class="boldy">Dirección</span>
                <span>{{person.locationId.streetAddress}}</span>
                <span class="boldy">Precio</span>
                <span>{{person.bookingPrice}}</span>
            </mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-title-group>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

And also created this select:

```
<select #slct name="" (change)="change(slct)">
    <option value="xx">Filtrar por precio</option>
    <option value="under">Over 2000</option>
    <option value="over">Under 2000</option>
</select>
```

the typescript c

Comment: use ``ngIf='person.bookingPrice > 2000'`` for your card

Comment: yes, but how can I connect the select with the displayed cards?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-container:

```
<mat-card #maty *ngFor="let person of dataArray">
     <ng-container *ngIf='person.bookingPrice > 2000'>
        <mat-card-title-group>....
     </ng-container>
</mat-card>
```